# probability that a prime power divides a product of $n$ positive integers

Tags: probability

Assume that $p$ is a rime number, that $r$ is a positive integer, and that $X_n$ is a product of $n$ "randomly chosen" positive integers. This means that we consider the $n$-fold Cartesian product ${\bf Z}/p^r{\bf Z}\times \cdots {\bf Z}/p^r{\bf Z}$, assume that ${\bf Z}/p^r{\bf Z}$ has the uniform probability distribution in which every residue class has a probability of $1/p^r$ of being chosen. What is the probability that $p^r$ divides a product ${X_n}={\prod}^{n}_{j=1}{x_j}?$
If $r =1$, then I seem to get $1-(1-(1/p))^n$ because $(1-(1/p))^n$ is the probability that a prime $p$ does *not* divide $X_n$, and I simply subtract this probability from $1$ to work out the probability that $p$ *does* divide $X_n$. Not sure how to treat the cases $p^2$, $p^3$ or more generally $p^r$.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but how do you randomly choose n positive integers? There are an infinite number of positive integers.

Comment: @barrycarter Right, there are no "uniform" distributions over an infinite set of integers, but the problem is pretty clear the idea is to work in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^r}$ which does have a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the notation $\nu_p(n)$ for the [$p$-adic order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order), the highest exponent $a$ where $p^a$ divides $n$.

So your uniform probability distribution gives

$$ \begin{align*}
P \big(\nu_p(x_j) \geq k \big) &= \frac{1}{p^k}, \qquad 0 \leq k \leq r \\
P \big(\nu_p(x_j) = r \big) &= \frac{1}{p^r} \\
P \big(\nu_p(x_j) = r-1 \big) &= \frac{1}{p^{r-1}} - \frac{1}{p^r} = \frac{p-1}{p^{r}} \\
P \big(\nu_p(x_j) = r-2 \big) &= \frac{1}{p^{r-2}} - \frac{1}{p^{r-1}} = \frac{p-1}{p^{r-1}} \\
& \vdots \\
P \big(\nu_p(x_j) = 1 \big) &= \frac{1}{p} - \frac{1}{p^2} = \frac{p-1}{p^2} \\
P \big(\nu_p(x_j) = 0 \big) &= 1 - \frac{1}{p} = \frac{p-1}{p}
\end{align*} $$

Now form a generating function from this sequence:

$$ f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^r P \big(\nu_p(x_j) = k \big) t^k $$

$$ f(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{r-1} \frac{p-1}{p^{k+1}} t^k + \frac{1}{p^r} t^r $$

$$ f(t) = \frac{p-1}{p} \frac{1-\left(\frac{t}{p}\right)^r}{1-\frac{t}{p}} + \frac{t^r}{p^r} $$

$$ f(t) = \frac{(p-1) (p^r - t^r) + (p-t) t^r}{p^r (p-t)} $$

$$ f(t) = \frac{p^{r+1} - p^r + t^r - t^{r+1}}{p^r (p-t)} $$

The number of times $p$ divides a product equals the sum of the number of times $p$ divides each factor. In terms of $\nu_p$, this is the equation

$$ \nu_p \left( \prod_{j=1}^n x_j \right) = \sum_{j=1}^n \nu_p(x_j) $$

So the probability the product has a given $p$-adic order is

$$ P\big( \nu_p(X_n) = k \big) = \sum_{k_1 + k_2 + \cdots k_n = k} \: \prod_{j=1}^n P\big( \nu_p(x_j = k_j) \big) $$

where the sum ranges over all possible $n$-tuples of non-negative integers which add up to $k$. Let $g$ be another generating function formed from this sequence:

$$ g(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{nr} P \big(\nu_p(X_n) = k \big) t^k $$

And the key thing then is that $g(t) = f(t)^n$, because when multiplying the polynomial $f$ by itself $n$ times, the coefficient of $t^k$ can be computed by selecting one term from each copy of $f$ so that the total powers add up to $k$, multiplying those coefficients together, than adding all such choices giving the same $t^k$ power. So the quantity we're looking for, $P \big(\nu_p(X_n) = k \big)$, is the coefficient of $t^k$ in the polynomial

$$ g(t) = \left[ \frac{p^{r+1} - p^r + t^r - t^{r+1}}{p^r (p-t)} \right]^n $$

One way to isolate a single coefficient would be by differentiating $k$ times, dividing by $k!$, and plugging in $t=0$:

$$ P \big(\nu_p(X_n) = k \big) = \frac{1}{k!} g^{(k)}(0) $$

Not a nice calculation, but it's a method.

Comment: Impressive calculation! I thought the best one could hope for was a recurrence relation.